# How to debug file from /vendor/

Tags: laravel-5

In my laravel 5.8 app I need to edit file
/vendor/paypal/rest-api-sdk-php/lib/PayPal/Core/PayPalHttpConnection.php
with debugging info
How can copy this file into my project and modify it ?
For production I will remove this file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should save this file somewhere, then modify it directly in vendor directory, and when you achieved your debug, discard the changes.